# Update table from one server to another

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in one server and I need to update same table which is in another server, using a trigger is not a good idea because I was having issues and I read is not a good approach.
I was thinking to use either extended events or service broker, I'm using SQL Server 2014. I don't want to create a SQL Job that runs like every minute to check if table has an insert/update/delete to copy the data into the other server. Not sure which one is the best for my purpose, For example TableA on Server 1 is updated, I need to reflect this update into the other TableA on Server 2 but only when any insert/update/delete happens.

Comment: You can use an ETL software, i recommend you to use SSIS or Pentaho DI.

Comment: Use [Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91888/mirror-replicate-only-1-table-of-a-database

Comment: thank you everybody, I will take a look those options